# White to transparent gradient with background image

Tags: css, gradient

I need to apply a white to transparent gradient which covers about a 1/4 of the top of the page and a background image visible for the rest of the page.

Im looking to achieve a seamless blend from a gradient to a textured image and to do this in CSS3.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I recommend [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator - ColorZilla.com](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

It's a well designed tool and there's a white to transparent preset.

[image: css gradient generator]

The CSS code that it generates for a white to transparent gradient is this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Mike, your 5 year old answer just saved me hours, thank you.

Comment: great answer, just updated to include the generated code. alternatively you can click this permalink to view it: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&1+0,0+100;White+to+Transparent

Comment: Many thanks. Been looking for this for 2 days. I tried everything I found on Stackoverflow and the web but this is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use another tool for gradients generation - [EnjoyCSS](http://enjoycss.com/).
It also allows to generate other CSS features like background, shadows, transitions etc.

[image]
White to transparent gradient generated with this tool:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-position: 50% 50%;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto auto;
background-size: auto auto;
```