# Change the level of opacity with height of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way in CSS or javascript or jquery that opacity of a single image can be changed along with its height. Like lets say I have an image 10px tall, I want the bottom 1px to be invisible so opacity would be 0, and second last pixel would be 0.1, and gradually increasing to opacity 1 for the uppermost pixel. This kind of gradual opacity should give a reflection kind of appearance which is what I am trying to achieve. I have researched and tried and all my research has not proven of any help. Help would be appreciated. I am tagging javascript and jquery as well as I am not sure if it can be achieved using css3 only.

Comment: Did you google? First hit: http://cow.neondragon.net/index.php/383-reflectionjs-demo

Comment: @c_kick I did research it on google and all I got was a code to hide the bottom part of the image with another div.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with simple css:

```
background-image: url(...), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rbga(255,255,255,1),  rbga(255,255,255,0));
background-image: url(...), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,1)), to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you can have image height from 0 to 1000 px: then

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script>
function img_height()
{
    height = $('#idd').height();

    $('#idd').css('opacity',height/1000); // change 1000 to max size of image
}

</script>

<img src='http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/0/885/modis_wonderglobe_lrg.jpg' height="821px" id="idd" style='opacity:0' onload="img_height()">
```

Play with height values to confirm opacity change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I'll try all of them out and the one that works for me, I will mark it as an answer. Thank you. Already upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, I found this on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397712/white-to-transparent-gradient-with-background-image) :

This site seems to do the job for you, it looks very promising.
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/